# Get invoking cloudwatch rule from AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

If I have a lambda that's only invoked from a cloudwatch rule, is there a way to get the invoking rule's ARN from the lambda without having it passed in via a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

See the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html). The schedule's ARN should be in the `event` parameter passed to your Lambda function.

Comment: Ah, so I'd need to write my Lambda to handle the raw `event` parameter rather than relying on AWS to deserialize the input into my custom POJO?

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your POJO, or just use a `Map` or something.